# Помогите с алгоритмом сравнения массивов

Tags: android, arraylist

У меня есть 2 ArrayList, которые периодически заполняются данными по следующему принципу:

Первый запуск: 
ArrayList1 содержит 3 числа: 111, 222, 333;
ArrayList2 содержит 3 числа: 111, 222, 333;
ArrayList1 очищается; 
ArrayList1 получает все значения ArrayList2;
ArrayList2 очищается;

Второй запуск:
ArrayList1 содержит: 111, 222, 333;
ArrayList2 содержит: 444, 111, 222;
ArrayList1 очищается; 
ArrayList1 получает все значения ArrayList2;
ArrayList2 очищается;

Третий запуск:
ArrayList1 содержит: 444, 111, 222;
ArrayList2 содержит: 555, 444, 111;
ArrayList1 очищается; 
ArrayList1 получает все значения ArrayList2;
ArrayList2 очищается.

И так далее. То есть периодически появляются новые значения и "сдвигают" прежние данные.
Вопрос: как эти новые значения заносить каждый раз в ArrayList3 ? То есть, добавить проверку: если появились новые значения (их количество заранее не известно), то заносить их в ArrayList3.

Comment: у любого `List` есть метод `contains()`, который возвращает `true`, если объект содержится в списке. Используя этот метод, вы можете проверять, есть ли объект уже в списке.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть вам использовать Set? Если объекты уникальные, то

```
Set s2 = ArrayList2.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set s1 = ArrayList1.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
s2.removeAll(s1);
```

И что осталось в s2 добавляйте в ArrayList3